# templates calling function error - No matching function for call to 'bubbleSort'

Tags: c++

No matching function for call to 'bubbleSort'. 
I have this two function in the same .hpp file.

```
template<typename T>
void bubbleSort(std::vector<T> &vec){
    T zacasen;
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<vec.size()-1; j++) {
            if(vec[j]>vec[j+1]){
                zacasen=vec[j];
                vec[j]=vec[j+1];
                vec[j+1]=zacasen;
            }
        }
    }
}

template < int N, typename T >
void sort(const std::vector<T> &vec){
    if(N==1){
        bubbleSort(vec);
    }else if(N==2){
        //quicksort(vec, 0, vec.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: So where is the `quicksort` function?  I don't see it.

Comment: sorry it's for bubbleSort. my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
void bubbleSort(std::vector<T> &vec)
```

but

```
void sort(const std::vector<T> &vec)
```

You can't call `bubbleSort(vec)` from within your `sort` because a `const std::vector<T>` is not an `std::vector<T>` (note the `const`) and there's no implicit conversion sequence that could turn it into one. Consequently, there's no viable function which overload resolution could pick here…

Why would your `sort` ask for a `const` vector to begin with? Since it doesn't return a new vector, the only way it could possibly do what its name suggests it would be doing is by reordering (i.e., modifying) the contents of the vector its given!?